# Slowing down UIScrollView scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm using a UIScrollView to programatically animate some content.

However, I need to slow down the scrolling of the view.

This is the code I am using for the scrolling:

`self.scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height), animated: true)`

I have tried to add `scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast` but it didn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5) { 
    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height)
}
```